# What password used to install Jshint on command line?

Tags: node.js, jshint

For the first time I'm using SublimeLinter Jshint. But in order to do so

1. I must download node js
2. use `npm install -g jshint`  with a sudo.

   It then asked for a password. What password is it referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unix Sudo means "Super User Do" so when you used sudo `npm install -g jshint` it is asking for the password of administrator of the computer. In your case, it might just be your password that you use for your account on your computer.

Comment: I am glad this helped you! Can you please accept my answer. :)